# Excel 2010 getting alerts on closing workbook

Tags: java, excel, excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010 and I am using java excel connector library (from www.moyosoft.com ) to open, read/write and close excel files.

I do not want to see any alerts while closing the workbook if it is not saved so I am using setDisplayAlerts to False.

But it is not working in Excel 2010. In Excel 2007, it used to work fine.

I searched on internet and came across this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/exceldev/thread/adbad831-d9fc-402a-9a00-8252d6fde3d4) and it says to set property AskToUpdateLinks to false. I did that also but i still get a pop up while closing the workbook.

Any ideas what I am missing and how can it be resolved?

Rgds,
Sapan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before closing the workbook call this: `workbook.saved = true` where workbook is the workbook you are closing.

This will tell Excel you actually did save the workbook (even though you didn't), and therefore will avoid the alert.

Edit: I just checked the documentation on what you are using. Try `workbook.setSaved(true)` which probably does what I indicated (the documentation doesn't indicate what that method does).